# pivot_longer() for multiple columns with different names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am a new R user and I was hoping to get some help with pivot_longer() to reshape my data from wide to short. My dataset includes survival probabilities for two cohorts as well as both their lower and upper confidence interval data points. I was hoping to arrange them in long format like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MG6L.png) so I can plot them in ggplot2. I appreciate any help thank you!

my data set is as follows

```
structure(list(Time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), Cohort1 = c(0.904255319148936, 
0.898936170212766, 0.887769261266023, 0.887769261266023, 0.887769261266023, 
0.87631417402388, 0.87631417402388, NA, NA, 0.87631417402388, 
0.864551567661143, 0.858629981581273, 0.852708395501402, NA, 
0.852708395501402, 0.846745399728665, 0.846745399728665, 0.840740113205766, 
NA, 0.840740113205766), Cohort2 = c(0.707462686567164, 0.692537313432835, 
0.683384837924912, 0.674232362416989, 0.674232362416989, 0.668074989244231, 
NA, 0.664996302657852, 0.664996302657852, 0.658781383941424, 
0.652507275522934, 0.649370221313689, 0.646217938685953, 0.643065656058216, 
0.630394411603867, 0.62722660049028, 0.624058789376693, 0.620890978263105, 
0.617723167149518, 0.614539027112665), C1Lower95 = c(0.852338104650895, 
0.846140749965675, 0.833054851312184, 0.833054851312184, 0.833054851312184, 
0.819696863257612, 0.819696863257612, NA, NA, 0.819696863257612, 
0.806043967960357, 0.799218079053227, 0.792429563598159, NA, 
0.792429563598159, 0.785616930383783, 0.785616930383783, 0.778778500012501, 
NA, 0.778778500012501), C1Upper95 = c(0.938570469008423, 0.934312293965728, 
0.92534844712446, 0.92534844712446, 0.92534844712446, 0.916056348120451, 
0.916056348120451, NA, NA, 0.916056348120451, 0.906427391600421, 
0.901537491012523, 0.8966168920045, NA, 0.8966168920045, 0.891638921203334, 
0.891638921203334, 0.886603579837755, NA, 0.886603579837755), 
    C2Lower95 = c(0.655564487332025, 0.640091667602195, 0.630607727619003, 
    0.62114710952213, 0.62114710952213, 0.614788099004335, NA, 
    0.611612499799214, 0.611612499799214, 0.605202384226936, 
    0.598734349944198, 0.595504428845739, 0.592259587632446, 
    0.589017489398546, 0.576004700295779, 0.572758317180272, 
    0.569514623188025, 0.566273601091399, 0.56303523423295, 0.5597807789553
    ), C2Upper95 = c(0.753046097156017, 0.738936670959587, 0.730275198102735, 
    0.721591223004285, 0.721591223004285, 0.715742377703966, 
    NA, 0.712814219355565, 0.712814219355565, 0.706901638437748, 
    0.700928732359048, 0.697938428282602, 0.694932646561064, 
    0.691924293962202, 0.679812432812405, 0.67677809121533, 0.673741229385084, 
    0.670701861632804, 0.667660001811057, 0.664601682804447)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have attempted to code this but my tables just doesn't look right

```
#use tidyr for pivot functions

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

km_curve <- read_excel(paste0(path = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/dataset for reshape test.xlsx"), skip = 1) %>% 
 transmute(
    Time = `Time (Days)`, 
   Cohort1 = `Cohort 1: Survival Probability`,
  Cohort2 = `Cohort 2: Survival Probability`, 
   C1Lower95 = `Cohort 1: Survival Probability 95 % CI Lower`, 
  C1Upper95 = `Cohort 1: Survival Probability 95 % CI Upper`, 
   C2Lower95 = `Cohort 2: Survival Probability 95 % CI Lower`, 
   C2Upper95 = `Cohort 2: Survival Probability 95 % CI Upper`) 

km_curve %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(-Time),
                         names_to = c("Cohort"),
                         values_to = c("Survival", "Lower95", "Upper95"), # name of new columns
                       values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

I want to pivot all my other columns with respect to Time. The names of my columns "C1Lower95" and "C2Lower95" for ex dont have special characters so I wasn't able to use names_sep() to pivot them into their own separate columns. Im having issues separating the survival probabilities and confidence intervals from my two cohorts and arranging them into the columns heading "Cohort", "Survival", "Lower95", and "Upper95"

Alternatively i have tried renaming my columns so the characters are separated by "_", but that hasn't worked either

```
km_curve <- read_excel(paste0(path = "/Users/xxx/Desktop/dataset for reshape test.xlsx"), skip = 1), skip = 6) %>% 
 transmute(
    Time = `Time (Days)`, 
    C_Cohort1 = `Cohort 1: Survival Probability`,
    C_Cohort2 = `Cohort 2: Survival Probability`, 
     C_C1Lower95 = `Cohort 1: Survival Probability 95 % CI Lower`, 
  C_C1Upper95 = `Cohort 1: Survival Probability 95 % CI Upper`, 
 C_C2Lower95 = `Cohort 2: Survival Probability 95 % CI Lower`, 
   C_C2Upper95 = `Cohort 2: Survival Probability 95 % CI Upper`) 


km_curve %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(-Time),
                         names_to = c(".value", "Cohort"),
                         names_sep = "_",
                         values_to = c("Survival", "Lower95", "Upper95"),
                      values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
km_curve <- km_curve %>% 
  rename(Lower951 = C1Lower95, 
         Lower952 = C2Lower95, 
         Upper951 = C1Upper95, 
         Upper952 = C2Upper95) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Time, 
               names_pattern="(.*)(\\d)", 
               names_to=c(".value", "num")) %>% 
  rename(Cohort = num, 
         Survival = Cohort)

head(km_curve)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
#    Time Cohort Survival Lower95 Upper95
#   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     0 1         0.904   0.852   0.939
# 2     0 2         0.707   0.656   0.753
# 3     1 1         0.899   0.846   0.934
# 4     1 2         0.693   0.640   0.739
# 5     2 1         0.888   0.833   0.925
# 6     2 2         0.683   0.631   0.730
```

The trick here is to rename the variables so the cohort number comes last in all of them.  Then you can use a regular expression `(.*)(\\d)` which identifies everything before the terminal digit in the name as the first part and just the terminal digit as the second part.

Comment: thank yous so much!!!